# What feelings do women and girls have when seeing genocide of her race?

Tags: pain, military-psychology, trauma

In my collage , I need to submit an article on Genocides in Ancient World

I collected many details and show to my guide

But he requested me to add about the psychological feelings does a female have when spectating (partial)  genocide of her race

Let I explain in detail :

There was a city in 1500 BC which was sacked by enemy army . The commander decided to kill the males and take females as slaves .

1.The people of the city were gathered in a big ground.

2.The soldiers will dig a large pit before the gathered people

3.The 10-20 soldiers with swords will stand on the edge of the pit in a single line side by side with 2 meters gap to each other .

4.Each and every soldier have 20-30 persons standing in queue in front of them

5.All of the women , where gathered and sat down some meters away from the pit

7.Now , the a man standing in the first of the queue come forward and kneel down before the soldier.

8.The soldier will cut the head (beheading) of man and push the body and head into the pit.

9. The women gathered watching them with tears and screams

10.This continues until all persons standing in the queue beheaded.

Now my question is , what are psychological feeling does the females experiences when they watching the beheading of their family and relatives

I need them in psychological terms , NOT simply anger , vengeance , sadness,pain  etc i.e not in  layman terms

Since I am a History student , I can't get it

Please explain me

(sorry for Bad English)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Have you been able to find anything online on the emotional effects of genocide?

Comment: @ChrisRogers .. No . I got only emotional effects after the genocide . I need the emotions when watching the genocide...

Comment: What is the difference between layman feelings and psychological feelings?